# how to hide zoomband axisX labels or make it smaller?

Tags: lightningchart

i expected that the number label in axisx of zoomband be hidden or make it smaller, it takes up a certain amount of space, which makes the chart  crowd, i cant find related API in lightningchart API doucmention, any useful advice to me ? thank u
[chart pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNFa6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i figure out the solution, to hide the axisX, we should using setTickStrategy( AxisTickStrategies.Empty ), here is the code:

zoomBandChart.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy( AxisTickStrategies.Empty )